# Use of derived class construction when derived class object is type compatible with base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
class baseClass{};
class derivedClass : public baseClass{};
baseClass *obj = new derivedClass ;     // For simplicity, I amn't providing any-
                                        // class members.
```

Though, `baseClass` and `derivedClass` construction takes place, `derivedClass` members are opaque to `obj`. Then, what is the use of `derivedClass` construction. BTW, I understand that `derivedClass` constructor invokes `baseClass` constructor and upon return `derivedClass` construction should take place. What is use of it anyway ? Just curious to know why it is so designed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, polymorphism. In more words, in a system where multiple classes are derived from a common base class it's the ability to treat objects of different derived classes in the same way, without worrying about their actual type.

Consider a drawing package that manages various shapes. You may choose to use an abstract base class called Shape that implements common methods such as Draw(), and perhaps has some common data members common to all shapes like x-pos and y-pos. You may then create some derived concrete classes like Ellipse and Square, which will take their own shape-specific constructor parameters and override the Draw() method from the abstract class. The Circle constructor might need x-pos, y-pos and radius, for example; it will use the radius parameter itself, but pass the x-pos and y-pos arguments to the inherited constructor.

You could then implement a Drawing() class that acts as a container of various Shapes, and iterate through that container to render your drawing without ever worrying about the actual type of the specific Shapes you're drawing.

Comment: +1 That's pretty much what I was trying to say, except infinitely more articulate.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale behind why `derivedClass` members get initialized is because if `derivedClass` has any virtual functions that override those declared in `baseClass` and those members reference data members of `derivedClass`, the initialization must occur or, when those functions are invoked, the results will be undefined.

In general, you won't be using inheritance unless you are trying to have polymorphic classes.  If the derived classes couldn't have their own state, then the base class would have to guess all of the possible data needed in derived classes, which would be a brittle, fragile approach to design.